# How to organize web app static file and folder structure?

Tags: web, directory, structure

I am using `bower.js` to keep `jquery` and `bootstrap` version ahead, and using `grunt.js` to minify and join files together

but some 3rd library like `bootstrap` have both js file and css file, where the whole `bootstrap` folder should I put? I have consider a structure like this:

```
project
|
|---build
|   |--js // minify jquery.min.js + bootstrap.min.js + script.min.js
|   |--css
|
|---src
|   |--js   //my own script.js file
|   |--css  //my own style.css file
|
|---bower_components
|   |---jquery
|   |---bootstrap
|
|---bower.json
|---Gruntfile.js
```

Is this appropriate?